# Dash home on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, unity-dash

I used Ubuntu 12.04 for a long time before and just I've upgraded to 16.04. Dash home on 12.04 has 3 items:
 
 - Recent Apps
 
 - Recent Files
 
 - Downloads
 
It was really convinient because I could open files so quick and without file manager. But now on 16.04 I seeing only "Installed" and "Dash plugins" on Dash home.

Is any way to set Dash-menu home on 16.04 to look like a 12.04?
 
[Dash in 12.04](http://www.linuxnov.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Dash-Home-Unity-5.2-Ubuntu-12.04-LTS-Precise-Pangolin.png)